# Activity is crashing whenever launched due to incorrect variable type declaration

Tags: android

My activity contains a `RecyclerView` that displays messages. Recently, I have made changes to my `RecyclerView` adapter and the `RecyclerView` layout, and now it's shows an error that a `LinearLayout` cannot be cast to a `CardView`. I don't know what's causing this.

Below is my `MessagesAdapter` file:

```java
    package blazestudio.com.blazemessenger.chats;

    public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<MessageModel> messageList;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    private ActionMode actionMode;
    private CardView selectedView;

    public MessagesAdapter(Context context, List<MessageModel> messageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messageList = messageList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.message_layout, parent, false);
        return new MessageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MessageModel message = messageList.get(position);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        String fromUserId = message.getMessageFrom();

        SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM");

        String dateTime = sfd.format(new Date(message.getMessageTime()));
        String [] splitString = dateTime.split(" ");
        String messageTime = splitString[1];

        if (fromUserId.equals(currentUserId))
        {
            if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT))
            {
                holder.llSent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.llSentImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO))
                {
                    holder.ivImageReceivedType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_video));
                }
                else if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE))
                {
                    holder.ivImageReceivedType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_image));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                holder.llSent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.llSentImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO))
                {
                    holder.ivImageReceivedType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_video));
                }
                else if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE))
                {
                    holder.ivImageReceivedType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_image));
                }
            }

            holder.llReceived.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.llReceivedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.tvSentMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
            holder.tvSentMessageTime.setText(messageTime);
            holder.tvImageSentTime.setText(messageTime);

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(message.getMessage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
                    .into(holder.ivSent);


        }
        else
        {
            if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT))
            {
                holder.llReceived.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.llReceivedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO))
                {
                    holder.ivImageSentType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_video));
                }
                else if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE))
                {
                    holder.ivImageSentType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_image));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                holder.llReceived.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.llReceivedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO))
                {
                    holder.ivImageSentType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_video));
                }
                else if (message.getMessageType().equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE))
                {
                    holder.ivImageSentType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_image));
                }
            }

            holder.llSent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.llSentImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.tvReceivedMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
            holder.tvReceivedMessageTime.setText(messageTime);
            holder.tvImageReceivedTime.setText(messageTime);

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(message.getMessage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
                    .into(holder.ivReceived);


        }

        holder.clMessage.setTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE, message.getMessage());
        holder.clMessage.setTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_ID, message.getMessageId());
        holder.clMessage.setTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE, message.getMessageType());

        holder.clMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String messageType = view.getTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE).toString();
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(view.getTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE).toString());

                if (messageType.equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (messageType.equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpg");
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

        holder.clMessage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                if (actionMode!=null)
                    return false;

                selectedView = holder.clMessage;

                actionMode = ((AppCompatActivity)context).startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallBack);

                holder.clMessage.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.longPress));

                return true;

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CardView llSent, llReceived, llSentImage, llReceivedImage;
        private TextView tvSentMessage, tvSentMessageTime, tvReceivedMessage, tvReceivedMessageTime, tvImageSentTime, tvImageReceivedTime;
        private ImageView ivSent, ivReceived, ivImageReceivedType, ivImageSentType;
        private CardView clMessage;


        public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            llSent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llSent);
            llReceived = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llReceived);
            tvSentMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSentMessage);
            tvSentMessageTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSentMessageTime);

            ivImageReceivedType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImageReceivedType);
            ivImageSentType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImageSentType);

            tvReceivedMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReceivedMessage);
            tvReceivedMessageTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReceivedMessageTime);

            clMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clMessage);

            llSentImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llSentImage);
            llReceivedImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llReceivedImage);
            ivSent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSent);
            ivReceived = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivReceived);

            tvImageSentTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSentImageTime);
            tvImageReceivedTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReceivedImageTime);

        }
    }

    public ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallBack = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_chat_options, menu);

            String selectedMessageType = String.valueOf(selectedView.getTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE));

            if (selectedMessageType.equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT))
            {
                MenuItem itemDownload = menu.findItem(R.id.mnuDownload);
                itemDownload.setVisible(false);
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem menuItem) {

            String selectedMessageId = String.valueOf(selectedView.getTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_ID));
            String selectedMessage = String.valueOf(selectedView.getTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE));
            String selectedMessageType = String.valueOf(selectedView.getTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE));

            int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch (itemId)
            {
                case R.id.mnuDelete: // Delete the message

                    if (context instanceof ChatActivity)
                    {
                        ((ChatActivity)context).deleteMessage(selectedMessageId, selectedMessageType);
                    }

                    actionMode.finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.mnuShare: // Share the message

                    if (selectedMessageType.equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT))
                    {
                        Intent intentShare = new Intent();
                        intentShare.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, selectedMessage);
                        intentShare.setType("text/plain");
                        context.startActivity(intentShare);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (context instanceof ChatActivity)
                        {
                            ((ChatActivity)context).downloadFile(selectedMessageId, selectedMessageType, true);

                        }
                    }

                    actionMode.finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.mnuForward: // Forward the message
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Forward: This feature is coming soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    actionMode.finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.mnuDownload: // Download file
                    if (context instanceof ChatActivity)
                    {
                        ((ChatActivity)context).downloadFile(selectedMessageId, selectedMessageType, false);
                    }
                    actionMode.finish();
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            actionMode = null;

            selectedView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.chat_background));

        }
    };

}
```

What could this mean and how could I resolve this?

Comment: can you post the crash stack trace?

Comment: Ok, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root view in your `message_layout.xml` layout file is a `LinearLayout` with id of `android:id="@+id/clMessage"`.

However in `MessageViewHolder`, you try to set that LinearLayout to a reference variable that's expecting a `CardView`:

`MessageViewHolder`:

```java
  private CardView clMessage;
  ...
  clMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clMessage); //clMessage is actually a LinearLayout
```

**Solution**: You need to change the type of `clMessage` to be `LinearLayout`.

**EDIT**: Well, this will fix your *immediate* crash. Upon reviewing your code a bit more, it seems like you'll get this error again down the line in `onBindViewHolder`: `selectedView = holder.clMessage;`. `selectedView` is of type `CardView`, but you're trying to set it to, what will now be after your changes, a `LinearLayout`. Review your layout file. It seems you're expecting to have a 5th CardView element that you didn't actually define.

Furthermore, I'd also suggest that you change your variable names and view IDs to be more descriptive. Layout IDs do typically break the 'no Hungarian naming' principle, but you have taken it overboard. Names like this can (and we've seen, do) lead to confusion and make your codebase harder to maintain. Try setting the IDs to more accurately describe what that view is for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. (I'm really bad at this)
I will take your ID suggestion into consideration in the future but at the moment, I'm going to keep all of my ID's the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. There isn't a 5th CardView in my message_layout.xml file. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @ojbqa You set the id of `clMessage` to be for a `LinearLayout` in your `message_layout.xml`. Yet you continuously try to set that LinearLayout to different `CardView` reference variables in your code. I'm asking: 1) is it just a mistake (in which case, change the instances from my original answer from `CardView` to `LinearLayout`, or 2) did you actually need a 5th CardView in your layout file and simply forgot to add it? I'm not familiar with your project, and your ID names don't give me much context on what you're trying to do, so I can't answer which of those 2 options is your case.

Comment: I have changed it from `CardView` to `LinearLayout` already, but I only have 4 CardViews in my message_layout.xml file, and those are all that I need in my layout.

Comment: @ojbqa Okay. Look at your `message_layout.xml`. The very first element of it is a `LinearLayout`. You named this LinearLayout `clMessage`. That LinearLayout named clMessage contains 4 `CardView`s. However, in your code, you keep trying to assign that `LinearLayout` named `clMessage` to a `CardView`. My question is: why? Do you actually NEED a 5th CardView? Or are you actually just trying to reference the parent LinearLayout? That is where you errors are coming from.

Comment: I'm trying to reference the parent LinearLayout.

Comment: @ojbqa Okay, so change `private CardView selectedView;` to `private LinearLayout selectedView;` Then change `private CardView clMessage;` to `private LinearLayout clMessage;`. Then re-run your app and tell me if it's still crashing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219524/discussion-between-ojbqa-and-kabumere).